# Combining two existing Terraform states as modules

Tags: terraform

Right now I have a Terraform project consisting of multiple directories:

```
root
|- stack
|- applications
   |- app1
   |- app2
   |- app3
```

- `Stack` contains all of the common dependencies for the apps.
- `app1`, `app2`, and `app3` use remote state to refer to `stack` resources.
- I currently have to run `terraform apply` in each of the four directories separately with separate `.tfvars`. (This was originally by design.)

I would like to refactor this project with a single `.tf` file in the root directory and the `stack`/`app*` directories as modules. I know how to do that just fine from a TF standpoint, but since this project is already deployed in two different environments, I'm trying to figure out the best way to migrate my existing `stack/app*` resources into a new combined state file or at least automate all the `terraform import` commands I'm going to need to run.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if hand-hacking the various state files is the best approach here.

Comment: I'm considering it, but I think I might be better off in the long run grabbing the IDs of all the resources from the existing state files and importing them into their new addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, it's been a long time.

I ended up writing a script to "harvest" the resource IDs from my old state using `terraform state show` and then another script to `terraform import` them into my new project's state. It wasn't particularly pleasant, but in the end it did what I needed it to do. That was Terraform v0.11.x stuff, too. State has become a lot easier to manage since then.

Comment: `State has become a lot easier to manage since then.`

How so? Would your answer/solution be different using the latest terraform version of today?

Answer (score 0):

Vincent is right, Terraform state mv won't do this. The idea was to Merge two state together.

My first suggestion, is to combine the entire project into a single main.tf, variable.tf ...or by making them a module by calling them one after the other in a single main.tf

Then terraform init, it will bring something like :

> Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...
Backend configuration changed!

Terraform has detected that the configuration specified for the backend
has changed. Terraform will now check for existing state in the backends.

Do you want to copy existing state to the new backend?
Pre-existing state was found while migrating the previous "gcs" backend to the
newly configured "gcs" backend. An existing non-empty state already exists in
the new backend. The two states have been saved to temporary files that will be
removed after responding to this query.

Previous (type "stateA"): C:\Users\xx\xx\xx\Temp\terraform447677407\xx.tfstate
New      (type "stateB"): C:\Users\xx\xx\xx\Temp\terraform447677407\yy.tfstate

Do you want to overwrite the state in the new backend with the previous state?
Enter "yes" to copy and "no" to start with the existing state in the newly
configured "stateB" backend.

Enter a value:
So you can decide whether to merge this states or use an new state. I will recommend to back up your states before doing this.

More information can be seen here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/mv.html#example-move-a-module-to-another-state

Comment: I don't think `terraform init` will do the trick. The terraform message `Terraform has detected that the configuration specified for the backend has changed` only deals with the situation where the state file has moved from, say, one S3 bucket to another bucket. But, after the re-init, the new state file won't contain more or new resources than the old state file.
The only solution I can think of so far is boiling down to `terraform import` command -- either composing that command manually or hacking up your own shell script to generate those commands like the original poster eventually did.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably going to want to use `terraform state mv` to move the state from each of the `app` states to the `stack` state. The exact usage will depend on the type of backend you use for your state. You can see an example of that from the documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html#example-move-a-module-to-another-state). Be sure to backup all of your state files before doing this so that you can easily recover in the event that something goes wrong.

Comment: The command `terraform state mv ...` won't do. It is only for renaming a resource's address inside the same state file rather than moving across 2 state files. I wish that command were better named to something like `terraform state rename-resource-address ...`.